# load customer collection by email and mobile but not general group

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I want to load customer collection by email and mobile but not general group

**for email load**

```
 $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
```

**for mobile**

```
 $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
 $customerCollection = $customer->getCollection()
                       ->addAttributeToFilter('mobile', $query)
                       ->getFirstItem();    
 $entityId =  $customerCollection->getEntityId();
```

Comment: You don't want to load general group customers?

Comment: No , i want only other group

Answer (score 0):

Try this for exclude Genereal group customer.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('neq'=>1));
```

Answer (score 0):

try This below Code for mobile and customer group not general

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('mobile', $query)
->addFieldToFilter('group_id', array('neq'=>1));
```